# Is it possible to bind a collection of Groovy Expandos to a jasper report?

Tags: grails, groovy, jasper-reports

I'm using the Grails Jasper report plugin in my application. Im trying to bind a collection of Expandos to my report template.

My Expando is built as follows

```
def calendarTask = new Expando() 
calendarTask.title = task.name 
calendarTask.date = new Date() 
data.add(calendarTask)
```

I then bind the collection in my controller

```
chain(controller:'jasper', action:'index', model:[data:data], params:params)
```

In my report I have a field called "title" (type string) defined in my report template. When I try and run this report I get the exception below. Can you bind Groovy Expando collection to jasper reports?

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   Unknown property 'title' on class
>   'class groovy.util.Expando'
>
> at
>   org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1313)
>
> at
>   org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:762)
>
> at
>   org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:837)

Comment: *I get the exception below...* -- think you forgot something ;-)

Comment: Haha, sure did! Its in there now :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a quick test script, and it gave the same error

```
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='commons-beanutils', module='commons-beanutils', version='1.8.3')
)
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean

def calendarTask = new Expando() 
calendarTask.title = { -> 'tim' }
calendarTask.date = { -> new Date() }

println new PropertyUtilsBean().getProperty( calendarTask, 'title' )
```

So it looks like `common-beanutils` and `Expando` don't play well together...

However, if you change from using `Expando` to just using a plain `Map`, the beanutils call works, so could you try changing your code to:

```
def calendarTask = [
  title : task.name,
  date  : new Date(),
]
data.add(calendarTask)
```

Comment: Thanks this now works :-) However because this is the second area of my code-base that effectively "wraps" this calendar task data I think its best in my specific case to encapsulate this in its own "CalendarTask" class.

Comment: Just checked, and it works fine with a `CalendarTask` class :-) Good luck!